# BigQuery Google Analytics: Double Visit Counts for Roll up Properties using totals.visits

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Currently experiencing an issue with bigquery query I'm using but specifically with roll up properties. The following query shows exactly double the amount of visits between the two visit calcualtions (visits and visits2) on certain dates. On other dates the numbers match and then on others they approximately double. Predominantly though, visits is double visits2. Any ideas why?

```
    SELECT
      date,
      geoNetwork.country AS Country,
      SUM(totals.visits) AS visits,
      COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST (visitId AS string),fullvisitorId)) AS visits2,
      COUNT(DISTINCT(fullVisitorId)) AS Users,
      SUM(totals.newVisits) AS new_,
      SUM(totals.pageviews) AS PAGEVIEWS,
      SUM(totals.bounces) AS BOUNCES,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN device.isMobile = TRUE THEN (totals.visits)
          ELSE 0 END) mobilevisits,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN trafficSource.medium = 'organic' THEN (totals.visits)
          ELSE 0 END) organicvisits,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN EXISTS(  SELECT 1  FROM UNNEST(hits) hits  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.eventInfo.eventAction,'register$|registersuccess|new registration|account signup|registro')) THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END) AS NewRegistrations,
      SUM(CASE
      WHEN EXISTS(  SELECT 1  FROM UNNEST(hits) hits  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.eventInfo.eventAction, 'add to cart|add to bag|click to buy|ass to basket|comprar|addtobasket::')) THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END) AS ClickToBuy,
  SUM(totals.transactions) AS Transactions,
  SUM(totals.transactionRevenue) /1000000 AS Revenue
FROM
  `project-1&&&&.dataset.ga_sessions*`
WHERE
  1 = 1
  AND PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)')) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01')
  AND TIMESTAMP('2017-05-08')
GROUP BY
  date,
  Country
ORDER BY
  visits DESC;
```

It looks like the issue is also happening with bounces, pageviews, mobilevisits and organicvisits.

If I have to go with the more manual version of visits2, I'm also going to need to the same for the other metrics can anyone point me in the direction of what the more accurate calculation for these are e.g. how to calculate bounces without using totals.bounces?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that your `ga_sessions*` wildcard is matching more tables than you intended?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you put in the `WHERE` clause the condition `and totals.visits=1`. Does it change something?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I didn't think so but added an _ after the table id and seems to have worked, was it querying both the ga_sessions and ga_sessions_intraday? It's weird I'm almost certain that when I first did this query the numbers were not double as I checked the visit numbers specifically...

Comment: @Will that slightly reduced some of the visit/user metrics but not to where they needed to be. I'll mark it as answered after I've done some further checking. Thanks both

Comment: seemed to work... although I have another issue now which I've put here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880721/google-analytics-metrics-are-inflated-when-extracting-hit-level-data-using-bigqu) if you both would be so kind to look!

Answer (score 0):

Elliot's comment was correct, it looks like I had to add an underscore (I went further and added "_2017" to ensure that the query was not querying the intra day tables. Interestingly this only seems to be an issue for roll up properties linked to BigQuery as this is not needed for normal properties, the wildcard format used in the original works just fine for the usual Google Analytics properties.