# Google Analytics Metrics are inflated when extracting hit level data using BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to display the source property name within the Google Analytics roll up property I have linked to bigquery. Issue is, is that when I try the below some of the metrics become hugely inflated. I'm guessing this is to do with repeated fields but not sure what to do about it. I've tried a number of workarounds like using "max" but this doesn't display every property name.

All metrics except users and visits seem to be inflated.

```
SELECT
  date,
  MAX(CASE
      WHEN EXISTS(  SELECT 1  FROM UNNEST(hits) hits  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId, r'82272640')) THEN 'MUG'
      WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      UNNEST(hits) hits
    WHERE
      hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId = 'Social') THEN 'Social'ELSE 'Website' END) AS Property,
  geoNetwork.country AS Country,
 COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(cast(visitId AS STRING),fullVisitorId)) as visits,
 sum(totals.visits) as visits2,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(fullVisitorId)) AS Users,
 h.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName as display,
  SUM((
    SELECT
      SUM(latencyTracking.pageLoadTime)
    FROM
      UNNEST(hits)
    WHERE
      page.pagePath = '/' ))/SUM((
    SELECT
      SUM(latencyTracking.pageLoadSample)
    FROM
      UNNEST(hits)
    WHERE
      page.pagePath = '/')) AS pageloadspeed,
  SUM(totals.newVisits) AS new_,
  SUM(totals.screenviews) AS PAGEVIEWS,
  SUM(totals.bounces) AS BOUNCES,
   sum(CASE
      WHEN device.isMobile = TRUE THEN (totals.visits)
      ELSE 0 END) mobilevisits,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN trafficSource.medium = 'organic' THEN (totals.visits)
      ELSE 0 END) organicvisits,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN EXISTS(  SELECT 1  FROM UNNEST(hits) hits  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.eventInfo.eventAction,'register$|registersuccess|new registration|account signup|registro')) THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END) AS NewRegistrations,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN EXISTS(  SELECT 1  FROM UNNEST(hits) hits  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.eventInfo.eventAction, 'add to cart|add to bag|click to buy|ass to basket|comprar|addtobasket::')) THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END) AS ClickToBuy,
  SUM(totals.transactions) AS Transactions
FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) as h
WHERE
  1 = 1
  AND PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)')) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2017-05-01')
  AND TIMESTAMP('2017-05-01')
GROUP BY
  date,
  Country,
  display
ORDER BY
  visits DESC;
```

EDIT:

I've tried simply removing UNNEST(HITS) hits as h from the FROM clause, this gave me the following error:

> Error: Cannot access field sourcePropertyInfo on a value with type ARRAY> at [16:14]

I've also tried using it in a subquery as follows:

```
(select h.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName from unnest(hits) h) as displayname,
```

and get the error:

> Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need to compute several values on the hits level maybe unnesting the field *hits* is the best approach. The downside is that you lose the *totals* field aggregation for the session level but still you can work it around.

As an example:

```
SELECT
  date,
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId, r'82272640') THEN 'MUG'
    WHEN h.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId = 'Social' THEN 'Social'ELSE 'Website'
  END AS Property,
  geoNetwork.country AS Country,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(visitId AS STRING),fullVisitorId)) AS visits,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(fullVisitorId)) AS Users,
  h.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName AS display,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagepath, r'/') THEN h.latencyTracking.pageLoadTime END) / SUM(CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagepath, r'/') THEN h.latencyTracking.pageLoadSample END) AS pageloadspeed,
  COUNT(DISTINCT
    CASE
      WHEN totals.newVisits = 1 THEN CONCAT(CAST(visitId AS STRING),fullVisitorId) END) new_visits,
  COUNT(CASE
         WHEN h.type = 'PAGE' THEN h.page.pagepath END) pageviews,
  SUM(CASE
       WHEN (h.isentrance = TRUE AND h.isexit = TRUE) THEN 1 END) bounces,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
        WHEN device.isMobile = TRUE THEN CONCAT(CAST(visitId AS STRING),fullVisitorId) END)) mobilevisits,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
        WHEN trafficSource.medium = 'organic' THEN CONCAT(CAST(visitId AS STRING),fullVisitorId) END)) organicvisits,
  SUM(CASE
       WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.eventInfo.eventAction,'register$|registersuccess|new registration|account signup|registro') THEN 1 END) AS NewRegistrations,
  SUM(CASE
       WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.eventInfo.eventAction, 'add to cart|add to bag|click to buy|ass to basket|comprar|addtobasket::') THEN 1 END) AS ClickToBuy,
  COUNT(h.transaction.transactionid) transactions
FROM
  `project_id.dataset_id.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS h
WHERE
  1 = 1
  AND PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)')) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2017-05-01') AND TIMESTAMP('2017-05-01')
GROUP BY
  date,
  Country,
  display,
  Property
```

I ran it against our dataset and it seems to be working. Some changes I did:

- Removed the `MAX` operation for the *Property* and added it to the group by.
- *pageviews* was considered as the count of hits where hit.type = 'PAGE'. Not sure if this is the same for screenviews though.
- bounce is computed when there's an entrance and exit event.
- Total transactions is a count on transaction ids (hopefully this field is being filled in your dataset as well).

Comment: thanks @will this was the best solution. There are still slight discrepancies though for the metrics though between this and what is reported in GA but I have no idea why

Comment: @AaronHarris just saw your other question and ended up seeing this comment. Try setting `AND totals.visits=1` in the `WHERE` clause. It might make results equal to what you see in the analytics reports.

Comment: Thanks Will. Still getting some errors but primarily with the number of bounce rates, it's much higher from the query than in GA

Comment: although if I use just the totals.bounces it seems to be much closer but I'm not sure how as it should be super inflated

Answer (score 1):

You're flattening your table in your most outer FROM statement (ie here:

*FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`**, UNNEST(hits) as h***)

All your session level dimensions eg device.* or totals.* values like totals.transactions are already rolled up to a session level, so when you flatten the table by unnesting the hits, these totals values get written as many times as there are hits. Example:
Let's say there are 30 hits in one session and 2 transactions, since you flatten/unnest your hits, you will be left with 30 rows containing totals.transactions =  2, so when you sum over them, the result would be that there were 60 transactions in this session.
Your users and visits don't get affected by this since you count distinct them, so any dupes get eliminated.

It looks to me as if you're query will work if you just remove the **, UNNEST(hits) as h** if you remove or adapt this line

*h.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName as display*

since you already unnest the hits within the select statement where required apart from in this particular line.

Comment: Hi @thomas C I've edited my question based on your feedback, I'm getting the stated errors unfortunately. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Yeah, you are now unnesting within (select h.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName from unnest(hits) h) as displayname), so this will return more rows than your original dataset has.  You can either wrap this into ARRAY()  (ie ARRAY(select h.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName from unnest(hits) h) ) as displayname ) or you could possibly aggregate the values of the array (i think the array_agg() function could be of help)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. If I wrap in ARRAY like you said then it asks me to group by hits, which it then gives me another error that you can't group by ARRAY. If I try wrapping in ARRAY_AGG, it says the query will work but I get the same Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element - am I missing something with the ARRAY_AGG?

Comment: would you be able to clarify at all? still keep getting similar errors

Comment: try this line instead: 
array_concat_agg(array(select (h.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName) from unnest(hits) h))  as displayname   and  remove display(/displayname) from the group by part of your query. This should run, hope it comes somehow close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

after UNNESTing an array, use MAX() instead SUMMing them up to report on session level matrices:

use:

> - MAX(totals.screenviews) AS PAGEVIEWS,
> - MAX(totals.bounces) AS BOUNCES,
> - MAX(totals.transactions) AS Transactions
> - ...
> - ...

instead of:

> - SUM(totals.screenviews) AS PAGEVIEWS,
> - SUM(totals.bounces) AS BOUNCES,
> - SUM(totals.transactions) AS Transactions

this should partially solve your issue. Let me know how it goes?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why the calculated bounce rate is much higher in the query from [William Fuks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1002277/willian-fuks) is the following

> WHEN (h.isentrance = TRUE AND h.isexit = TRUE) THEN 1 END) bounces

It seems that isEntrance and isExit only happens on PAGE hits and so does not account for events. Hence the over count of bounces is due to single page views that might have had one or more interaction events happen on the page.