# BigQuery - Why is UNNEST operator not required for pulling transactions data in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-bigquery

```
SELECT SUM(totals.totalTransactionRevenue)
```

FROM bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_* 
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170701' AND '20170701';

Transactions are a product level scope and one session can have multiple transactions. So, a session could hold an array of transactions. In such a case, why is the UNNEST parameter not required to run this query?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the fields you selected is a simple INTEGER field and not ARRAY. You can check this by going to the Schema tab of the table. If the field contains ARRAY, it (or its parent field) should have the type "RECORD - REPEATED".

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have given you're counting transactions as a sum of `SUM(totals.totalTransactionRevenue)`. Note that `totals` contains aggregated data (as an interger, as the previous post explains), already unnested for you, that's why you don't need to `UNNEST` to read data from a field under `totals`.

You are correct in that if you wanted to ask another question from product level data, which hasn't already been aggregated for you in `totals`, (for example all of your transaction IDs from yesterday) then you need to unnest.

Also note that when you `UNNEST` you'll be duplicating the rows of `totals`, so be careful when using both in the same query, as you could end up double counting.

This previous answer explains this further, with some examples:
[Unnest and totals.timeOnSite (BigQuery and Google Analytics data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231791/unnest-and-totals-timeonsite-bigquery-and-google-analytics-data)